# Flutter: GridView with dynamic height cards for each row (X-Axis items)

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I've product cards that have different heights depending on the content similar to the image provided below.

The cards on the same row/level (X-Axis) should be set to match the height of the max item card on that row/level. The product cards I'm having could have titles fit one or two lines and different widgets with different heights (Like discounts and free shipping icon).

I've tried using [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-readme-tab-) but there's nothing like what I asked for in it.

My current thoughts are creating `ListView` with `children` as `Row` containing the cards as if it was `CrossAxisCount` and the `Row` is wrapped with `IntrinsicHeight` to ensure that children are set to max-height, but hoping that there is a cleaner solution.

[image]